# How to reopen a closed window with the Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi, button, window

I'm making a buttons in a main window ( hwnd ) that when you click on a button it opens new window ( hwndSec ) that can be controlled by the main window ! 
when i click on a button, the hwndSec showed up ! and while i'm clicking on the other buttons it can be modified ... but when i close it and attempt to reopen it again it doesn't response ! so the buttons become useless !
This a simple example of a single button just to open the window then trying to open it again.

The setting i set for hwndSec:

```
wincl.hInstance = hInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = "HwndSecClass";
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedureSec;      
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 
wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

/* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      
wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
    return 0;

hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,                   
       wincl.lpszClassName,        
       _T("Window 2"),       
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       
       500,                 
       500,                 
       HWND_DESKTOP,        
       NULL,                
       hInstance,       
       NULL                
       );
```

i make two window procedures :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedureSec (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

when i click a button i call this fonction :

```
ShowWindow(hwndSec,SW_SHOW);
```

and then the second window appear normally ,  when i close the window it doesn't came back to appear again.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
 {
 case WM_CREATE:
    CreateWindow("BUTTON",
                "open",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,
                200,100,
                100,50,
                hwnd,
                (HMENU) ID_BUTTON,
                NULL,
                NULL);
    break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case ID_BUTTON :
        //printf("%s",(char*)GetLastError());
        ShowWindow(hwndSec,SW_SHOW);
        break;
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedureSec (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
switch (message)
{
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is closed.  It is no more.  It has ceased to be.  It is expired and has gone to meet its maker.  It is a dead parrot.  You'll have to call CreateWindow() again.

Comment: Or you could just hide that window and use ShowWindow to show it again

Comment: The code demonstrates an abundant lack of insight. You really need to start over, and get the basics straight first. Get a good book, like Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: `WindowProcedureSec()` is infinite recursion waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a window is being closed, it receives a [`WM_CLOSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617.aspx) message. If that message is passed to `DefWindowProc()`, the default behavior is to *destroy the window*:

> An application can prompt the user for confirmation, prior to destroying a window, by processing the `WM_CLOSE` message and calling the `DestroyWindow` function only if the user confirms the choice.
>
> **By default, the `DefWindowProc` function calls the `DestroyWindow` function to destroy the window.**

This is further discussed on MSDN:

[Closing the Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381396.aspx)

So, you will have to re-create your secondary window with `CreateWindow/Ex()` each time you want to show it after it has been closed:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    ...
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_BUTTON :
            if (!hwndSec)
            {
                hwndSec = CreateWindowEx(
                    0,
                    _T("HwndSecClass"),
                    _T("Window 2"),
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    500,
                    500,
                    HWND_DESKTOP,
                    NULL,
                    hInstance,
                    NULL
                );
            }
            ShowWindow(hwndSec, SW_SHOW);
            break;
        }
        break;
    ...
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedureSec (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        hwndSec = NULL;
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

If you don't want to do that, then you need to make the secondary window handle the `WM_CLOSE` message and not pass it to `DefWindowProc()`.  For instance, call `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)` instead, and then you can later call `ShowWindow(SH_SHOW)` when needed

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    ...
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_BUTTON :
            ShowWindow(hwndSec, SW_SHOW);
            break;
        }
        break;
    ...
    }

    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedureSec (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for your help ! the both of these works ! 
Am just start using c++ ( windows.h  include...) so i don't know all the messages that can be receive on the WindowProcedure() like WM_CLOSE .. :p 
am doing my Best  :D

Comment: Some of the basic common window messages you can receive are listed here: [Window Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468922.aspx).